# Webpack 2: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to include .scss file it always throwing this error:

`Expected 'styles' to be an array of string`

Previously when I was using webpack 1 everything was working fine, I tried 3 different ways but none of them worked  all there are here:

```
1. styles: [require('../../../static/v4/angular/scss/main.scss')]
2. styles: [String(require('../../../static/v4/angular/scss/main.scss'))]
1. styles: [require('../../../static/v4/angular/scss/main.scss').toString()]
```

Here is my loaders:

```
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader'})
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        use: [{loader: 'raw-loader'}]
      }, { 
        test: /\.scss$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        use: [{
                loader: "to-string-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
      }, {
```

Comment: Have you tried to map back to the generated source? `styles: [require('../../../static/v4/angular/scss/main.scss')]` should be correct, but it can be undefined if there was some configuration error.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi what you mean by `map back to the generated source`, if you are talking about the path then path is correct, as it was working before in webpack 1

Comment: Please check the output of webpack, as this looks like a runtime error.

Comment: while running npm run build I got that error, so there is no output

Comment: Try using a `./` before `styles: [require('./../../../static/v4/angular/scss/main.scss')]`

Answer (score 5):

Try this for loading scss files using the below code.

```
{
    test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
    use: [                    
        'raw-loader',
        'sass-loader',
    ]
},
```

import scss like this in components

```
styleUrls: ['./style.scss'],
```